# how can i break lines in gwt button

Tags: gwt, button, line, break

Hi I tried and Googled a lot,  but I can't figure out, how to break the line of button. I#m using GWT Widgets and no HTML, that's why it's not that easy.
I just found examples for labels, but noone for buttons. Do u have an idea?

Comment: what do you mean by breaking line in button?

Comment: i wanna do this. `this.laneRequest.setText(this.currentStatus + '\n' + " Selection is required.");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a line break i.e. `<br/>` instead of `\n` and `setHTML` instead of `setText`

This will suffice:

```
this.laneRequest.setHTML(this.currentStatus + "<br/> Selection is required.");
```

`setText` takes normal String argument and `setHTML` takes html code argument.

Comment: Check the edited one. Use `setHTML` function or use `new Button(this.currentStatus + "<br/> Selection is required.")`. Both of these take html code as argument.